# Melt and dcast an awkward dataframe

Tags: r, reshape2

I'm working with a data frame that looks like this.  I would like to to look like:

province : district :  party A votes : party A Percent : party B votes : party B percent : party C votes : party C percent

Right now the candidate name is functioning well as a unique identifier to avoid the need for an aggregation function, but I ultimately will be OK dropping it.

```
candidate<-c('bob jones', 'bobby jones', 'sara jones', 'sara norah', 'nora jones', 'other name', 'name other', 'thomas name', 'name judge', 'my mayor', 'peter peter', 'paul paul')
party<-rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 4)
district<-c(rep('District 1', 3), rep('District 2', 3), rep('District 3', 3), rep('Disctrict 4', 3))
province<-c(rep('Province 1', 3), rep('Province 2', 3), rep('Province 3', 3), rep('Province 4', 3))
votes<-round(rnorm(12, mean=5000, sd=1000),0)
percent<-round(rnorm(12, mean=37, sd=10),2)
df<-data.frame(party, district,province, votes, percent, candidate)
```

I'm workng with these commands

```
df.test<-melt(df, id.vars=c('candidate', 'province', 'district', 'party'))
dcast(df.test, candidate+province+district~variable+party, value.var=c('value'))
```

It's close, put it's not creating one row per district, it's creating four rows per district.  The thing is: in my sample data set, when I drop 'candidate' from my casting call, this sample data set works great,e.g.

```
dcast(df.test, district~variable+party, value.var=c('value'))
```

But when I use the same call in my data set, I no longer have the unique identifier and this aggregates on length.

Hope you can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `data.table v1.9.5`, `dcast` can cast on multiple `value.var` columns. With that you can do:

```
require(data.table) #v1.9.5+
ans = dcast(setDT(df), province + district ~ party, value.var = c("votes", "percent"))
#      province    district votes_A votes_B votes_C percent_A percent_B percent_C
# 1: Province 1  District 1    3072    3149    4262     34.29     18.45     19.20
# 2: Province 2  District 2    5918    3970    4201     36.56     46.22     43.16
# 3: Province 3  District 3    5593    5208    5260     26.58     31.20     39.00
# 4: Province 4 Disctrict 4    6138    4537    6293     43.97     43.62     32.48
```

If you'd like a `data.frame` back, then you can do `setDF(ans)` to convert `ans` to `data.frame`.

You can install `v1.9.5` by following [these instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base solution:

```
set.seed(1)
candidate<-c('bob jones', 'bobby jones', 'sara jones', 'sara norah', 'nora jones', 'other name', 'name other', 'thomas name', 'name judge', 'my mayor', 'peter peter', 'paul paul')
party<-rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 4)
district<-c(rep('District 1', 3), rep('District 2', 3), rep('District 3', 3), rep('Disctrict 4', 3))
province<-c(rep('Province 1', 3), rep('Province 2', 3), rep('Province 3', 3), rep('Province 4', 3))
votes<-round(rnorm(12, mean=5000, sd=1000),0)
percent<-round(rnorm(12, mean=37, sd=10),2)
df<-data.frame(party, district,province, votes, percent, candidate)


reshape(df, direction = 'wide', times = c('votes','percent'),
        idvar = c('province', 'district'), 
        timevar = 'party', drop = 'candidate')

#       district   province votes.A percent.A votes.B percent.B votes.C percent.C
# 1   District 1 Province 1    4374     30.79    5184     14.85    4164     48.25
# 4   District 2 Province 2    6595     36.55    5330     36.84    4180     46.44
# 7   District 3 Province 3    5487     45.21    5738     42.94    5576     46.19
# 10 Disctrict 4 Province 4    4695     44.82    6512     37.75    5390     17.11
```